# compare two file and get only diffe name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two files f1 and f2

```
 df1:
         Co_Name         location   Name    ...         pr_vaule  Jr_value
0    India          India-01        AAAA    ...       1351.68         74.14
1    India          India-02        BBBB    ...       1351.68         61.03
2    India          India-03        CCCC    ...       1351.68         68.70
3    India          India-04        DDDD    ...       1351.68         64.36
4    India          India-05        FFFF    ...      10240.00       1208.32


[573 rows x 5 columns]


df2
        Co_Name         location           Name
0    India          India-01                 AAAA
1    India          India-02                 CCCC
2    India          India-03                 DDDD

.
[341 rows x 3 columns]

Expected :
         Co_Name         location   Name    ...         pr_vaule  Jr_value
1    India          India-02        BBBB    ...       1351.68         61.03
4    India          India-05        FFFF    ...      10240.00       1208.32
```

Please help me to fix this.

I tried
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=",", header=0)
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=",", header=0)
print(df2)

df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', indicator=True)
print(df3[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only'][['location ', 'Name']])

getting error:
Columns: [location, Name]
Index: []

Comment: You’re not specifying the keys (column names) that define the join

Comment: you mean  sep=",",  need specify ?